# How to dismiss a ContextMenu without the Back button?

Tags: android, android-activity, contextmenu, clicklistener

The application has a contextmenu opened and I want to close/dismiss it without using the back button. Is it possible to receive a click event somewhere so I can call close?

```
closeContextMenu ()
```

Or can I call

```
setCancelOnTouchOutside()
```

somewhere like I can on a Dialog? Alternative for me is to refactor all my context menu's to PopupWindows which can also do

```
setOutsideTouchable()
```

Anyone a good hint/idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dispatch a key event (back)and you're done.

```
myView.getRootView().dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
```

Comment: I can use closeContextMenu instead of your solution but the problem for both implementations is that I don't have any event which could trigger these close-solutions. I want to have a 'çlicked-outside-context-menu-listener' where I can put this code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing a cancel listener type of behavior like you'd use in a dialog, but why not just use the back button?